# how to set height of ComboBox in Vaadin

Tags: combobox, vaadin

As noticed, the combobox's height in Vaadin is 24px by default. Is there anyway to change the height? since setHeight(30, UNITS_PIXELS) doesn't work. the layout will be ruined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java:

```
comboBox.addStyleName("combobox-height-style");
```

CSS:

```
.v-filterselect-combobox-height-style {
    min-height: 30px;
}

.v-filterselect-combobox-height-style .v-filterselect-input {
    min-height: 30px;
}

.v-filterselect-combobox-height-style .v-filterselect-button {
    min-height: 28px;
}
```

The icon for the dropdown is a sprite and shouldn't be stretched, better to make a new resource image that is 30x30 pixels and use that as an icon. Eg:

```
.v-filterselect-combobox-height-style .v-filterselect-button {
    min-height: 28px;
    background: url("../img/dropdown_icon_30x30.png") no-repeat scroll transparent;
}
```

Comment: That helped me clear my mind, but still creating a new image is not my things. anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Jeffrey.W.Dong and btw, if you think my answer was what you were looking for it would be great if you wanted to mark it as "accepted answer"! =)

Comment: @Jeffrey.W.Dong no problem, you click the "check" icon right next to the answer. It'll help others who have the same issue as you by seeing that there is an answer that solves the problem. =)